# Joda-Time Library failing to load

Tags: android, eclipse, jodatime

I'm using Joda-Time libraries `org.joda.time.DateTime` and `org.joda.time.Days`, and i've imported both in the Project.

I also put the main .jar file in an user library for the project and both the source and javadoc .jars in the right place as attachments. (Joda-Time 2.1) I then declared the use of the libraries in the Manifest.

I'm getting an error from PackageManager saying:

`Package com.example.igestao (my package) requires unavailable shared library org.joda.time.DateTime; failing!`

And it just aborts the launch..

Any ideas ? 
Thanks.

EDIT: This is on Eclipse IDE btw.

Comment: joda time aint on ya classpath

Comment: well.. i put it on the Java Build Path.. hence my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, i just did it all over again from scratch, and i added the external JARs, instead of adding them from the WorkSpace..

Hope this helps someone else..